# How to include a long vertical line in html or jsp page?

Tags: html, jsp, line

I need to draw a vertical line on my page and unable to do it using any kind of hr style tags. even if it comes I am not able to ad=just the length.How do I do that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Homepage</title>
</head>
 <LINK href="styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
<img src="C:\virclipse\first.png"  width="1050" height="150">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div align="center">
<font face="Algerian" size="6">WELCOME TO V-LAUNCHPAD</font>
</div>
<hr size=6 color="black">
<div id= "abc" style="margin: -10px 0px 0px 200px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>


css stylesheet

@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
#abc{
    width: 6px; 
    background-color: black; 
    height: 5000%;
    float: left;


}
```

Comment: try this  http://jsfiddle.net/9t3sn/3/

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `div` of `0px` width, and height of your choice with borders:

```
<style>
    .vertical-line {
        width: 0;
        border: 1px solid green;
        height: 400px
    }
</style>
<div class="vertical-line"></div>
```

`hr` [by definition](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/hr) is supposed to be a **horizontal rule**.

Comment: @user3045921 Consider accepting my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

if you want verticle line using html `<hr>` tag you should set the width and size in your `<hr>` tag

```
<hr width="1" size="200" />
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/9t3sn/3/)

Comment: the link which you gave to see the demo is working i mean the length of the vertical line is being increased when i change the value to 800 but the same is not working in html.

Comment: The `width` and `size` attributes are [unsupported on the `<hr>` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/hr.html) as of HTML5.